# Lower bound on the number of balanced graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, asymptotics, random-graphs, lower-bounds

Let $\alpha>1$ be a constant and define $B_n$ as the number of (labeled) *balanced* graphs with $n$ vertices and $\left\lceil \alpha n\right\rceil $ edges. The paper [Strongly Balanced Graphs
and Random Graphs](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/avince/files/StronglyBalanced.pdf) by A. Ruciński and A. Vince implies that $B_n\geq1$. What better lower bounds are known? In particular, is it known to be bounded from below by $n^{(1+o(1))\alpha n}$?

Edit: adding a definition of balanced graphs. The *density* of a graph $G$ with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges is $$\mathrm{den}(G)=\frac{e}{v}$$
A graph $G$ is *balanced* if $\mathrm{den}(G)\geq \mathrm{den}(H)$ for every subgraph $H$ of $G$. Balanced graphs appear naturally when counting copies of a given graph in the random graph, as explained in the paper I referred to.

Comment: Adding a definition would enhance your chance of getting a good response.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thanks, I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bound of Ruciński and Vince is for *strongly balanced*, which is a more strict condition. If only *balanced* is required, the example of connected regular graphs provides a bound much greater than $n^{\Omega(n)}$.

The total number of regular graphs with $n$ vertices is
$$\alpha(n) \frac{2^{n^2/2}\sqrt{2e}}{\pi^{n/2} n^{n/2}},$$
where $\alpha(n)$ is a constant depending on $n\pmod{4}$.

B. D. McKay and N. C. Wormald, [Asymptotic enumeration by degree sequence of graphs of high degree](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019566981380042X), European J. Combin., 11 (1990) 565-580.

Note that the formula is stated for all regular graphs, not necessarily connected, but the vast majority of regular graphs are connected. (All degrees apart from 0,1,2 guarantee almost sure connectivity.)

Comment: Great, only balanced is required and this exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Dear Brendan, I'm taking a closer look and now I see that there's one condition missing, and it is the average degree. I need to count only graphs with density close to $1/\alpha$, which means average degree $2/\alpha$. Regular graphs do not generally cover this case, as the average degree can be fractional. Maybe something in the same nature can be said about almost regular graphs (in which $\Delta=\delta+1$)?

Comment: Right. Such near-regular graphs are not always balanced but I suspect most of them are. With a rough calculation I think the requirement is that for any subset $U$ of vertices, the number of edges between $U$ and $V$ is at least $|U|(n-|U|)/n$. Needs checking!